# Update position of row in a database table android

Tags: android

I have a Database table in android with 5 rows. I want to change the position of 3rd row to 1st position on click of a button.

Comment: You should remove all the rows from the table and then re-inserting them in the right order. I don't think this is a great idea, you probably should add a new column representing the "logical order" of the rows and use it in your code